# What type of ItemsControl is used in Nuget Packages Dialog for Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am just wondering which ItemsControl they are using, is it something of their own or its a regular ListBox with some styling ?

Here is the screenshot

[image: Nuget dialog]

I am trying to get a similar one, which one you would recommend ?

Comment: It is a ListView. You can use tools like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out for yourself.

Comment: I have latest version of Snoop but it always picks up the Main Window, not the dialog. I have tried using that Crosshair thing, that picks up the MainWindow not the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `ListView`. If you used `Snoop` and focus on the `PackageManagerWindow` then you will see the `UIElements` that makes up for it. The crosshair only launches `Snoop` on the dropped window. If you want to focus you need to use `CTRL` + `SHIFT` and click the element you want to snoop on.

[image]